# filteredArrayUsingPredicate not working

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I'm trying to use filteredArrayUsingPredicate with an array that has been built from data in a .plist file. Somehow it never seems to filter my array.

this is how my array is built:

```
    DrillDownAppAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (DrillDownAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.tableDataSource = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Rows"];
    copyDataSource = [ tableDataSource mutableCopy];
```

and then my predicate goes like this,

```
NSString *searchFor = search.text;
[tableDataSource release];
tableDataSource = [copyDataSource mutableCopy];
if ([searchFor length] > 0) {
NSLog(@"array = %@",tableDataSource);
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Self beginswith[c] %@",searchFor];
    [tableDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` returns a *new array* that contains the results
- `-[NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:]` filters in-place.

So use the following instead:

```
[tableDataSource filterUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need quotes round the string your subsituting into the predicateWithFormat: method. i.e:

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith[c] \"%@\"",searchFor];

Also try using the word "self" as all lower case, as in the keyword "self", and remember that instances of objects should really be started with a lowercase letter. For example, "appDelegate".